# "The request's session was deleted before the request completed. The user may have logged out in a concurrent request"

Tags: python, django

"The request's session was deleted before the request completed. The user may have logged out in a concurrent request" I am facing this error when trying to use 2 request.session().

In my code my using two request.session() to store variables.After one request successfully completed,its going to another request and throwing this error.

```
request.session['dataset1'] = dataset1.to_json()

request.session['total_cols'] = total_cols // getting error here
```

Please help to resolve the same.

Comment: Can you show your `SESSION_ENGINE` and `CACHES` settings?

Comment: I followed a different approach. It worked for the current code. Actually I am trying to read CSV data, but I guess since I was trying to add a huge data in the session object, the database was not able to store it and throwing this error.

Comment: If you've solved your current issue, please add a response to your answer with your working solution and mark it as resolved. If you have another issue, it would be better to create a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Since my dataset has 8000 rows, It was not a good idea to store in session variables. I have written some rest calls and that solved my problem.